# Proving that there exists a continuous function $f : M \to \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x) ≥ 0$ for all $x ∈ M$ such that $U$ = {$x ∈ M:f(x) > 0$}?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $U ⊆ M$ be an open set. I'd like to prove that there exists a continuous function

$f : M \to \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x) ≥ 0$ for all $x ∈ M$ such that $U$ = {$x ∈ M:f(x) > 0$}.

I have an answer, but it relies on the infimum and is very specific. Is there another easier to understand the solution? I cannot really understand what is going on after multiple tries of decoding it. Thank you!

The solution I was given: (I know its somewhat against rules to post pictures, but I am bad with latex).

[image]

Comment: Hi, I guess what I am looking for is a more rigorous way of coming to the solution.

Comment: What is assumed about $M$?

Comment: That it is any arbitrary metric space.

Comment: Well, if you need to prove it for an arbitrary metric space, chances are that the solution you posted is pretty much as simple as it gets. On the other hand, there is a simpler proof if you assume that $M=\mathbb R$.

Comment: That proof needs a little bit more work. What happens if $U=M$?